# How to create a grid within magento admin to display DB table information

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

Basically I have custom table for customer details. And I wanted to make a grid of all values from that table in admin panel.

Comment: have u created the menu in admin?

Comment: no.. Ineed to do it from scratch.. If anyone have good document then please provide.